# Xcode 12 and iOS 15

Tags: ios, xcode, build, xcode12, ios15

Is it possible to add somehow iOS 15.0 simulator to Xcode 12.4? (and build & run the project)

I have both xcode 12.4 and xcode 13.
I can't build my project in xcode 13.
I can build it only in xcode 12.4
But I would like to run my project on iOS 15, Is it possible to run?
If Yes, then how can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Useful question for me as my machine (Late 2012 Mac Mini) means I cannot upgrade beyond macOS Catalina (10.15) which in turn means I cannot upgrade Xcode beyond 12.4. So, no iOS 15 development for me until I can afford a new machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot have iOS 15 simulator in Xcode 12.4.

You can install it on physical iOS 15 device via TestFlight or by manually dragging the `.ipa`/product to the phone in Xcode “Devices” window or Finder. But when you do this, you cannot debug it interactively via the Xcode debugger.

---

Just as a heads-up:

> Starting April 2022, all iOS and iPadOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 13 and the iOS 15 SDK.

So, you’ll need to fix your Xcode 13 issue by then. See [App Store submissions now open for iOS 15 & iPadOS 15](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=f87q5n2j).

Comment: I hate apple so much