# Can you use Xcode 12.4 (IOS 10) to build on devices and or simulator with iOS 15?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have seen and followed those posts :

- [Is there a workaround for Xcode 12.4 to work on Ios 15?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69907738/is-there-a-workaround-for-xcode-12-4-to-work-on-ios-15)
- [Could not locate device support files in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54624850/could-not-locate-device-support-files-in-xcode)
- [Xcode 12 and iOS 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69883629/xcode-12-and-ios-15)

Some say yes, some say no.

I have found and downloaded the version 15 DeviceSupport files, but my Xcode still does not show build possibilities with iOS 15 simulators. I don't understand why I can't get this done.

And when I try to run on a physical device, I get an error message :

> Details
>
> ### Unable to install "fmsappreact" Domain:
> com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code: -402620375
> -- The code signature version is no longer supported. Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code: -402620375 User Info ...

Is it definitively outdated and impossible to run in this context?

I saw there was maybe a workaround by manually dragging the .ipa/product to the phone in Xcode “Devices” window or Finder. Where can I find this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> I saw there was maybe a workaround by manually dragging the .ipa/product to the phone in Xcode “Devices” window or Finder. Where can I find this?

Are you asking where the `.ipa`/product file is?

- You can find the `.app` file by doing a build for “Any iOS Device (arm64)” and. Go to your derived data folder (found in “Xcode” » “Preferences” » “Locations” and click on little arrow next to derived data folder). Then go to folder for your app and look for the “Build” » “Products” subfolder.

  Sometimes your derived data folder can have a lot of stuff in it. You can confirm the precise location if you go to Xcode’s “Report Navigator”, click on your successful build, scroll to the bottom of the log, and click on the little handle to the right of the message in the report next to one of the links related to your app:

  [image]
- You can create an `.ipa` file via “Product” » “Archive”. When the archive is done and you are presented with the “Organizer” window:

  [image]

  From there you can click on “Distribute App” » “Ad Hoc”, and after a few screens with a few options, when it is done, you will be presented with a final dialog box with “Export” button:

  [image]

  The resulting folder will have the `.ipa` file.
- However you find the path to the `.ipa`/`.app` file, you can then drag that to the Xcode “Devices” window:

  [image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! do you think it will allow me to build the app on an iOS 15 device? I will be able to try Wednesday if everything is alright.